# Deegree: how to validate if the GMLObject is (topological) correct?

Tags: deegree

How can I validate the (topological) correctness of a Deegree GMLObject?

When performing a gmlObject.toString() - to get the WKT string - I get a weird result: “MULTI… […]”. The last part of the "[...]" is literal.

So, I suspice that the topo is not correct. How to proof that?

I could validate the object via JTS. Converting the object via WKT to JTS fails, because JTS.WKTReader is complaining about the literal "[...]".

The simplified object is:

[image]

The GML is:

```
        <gml:Surface srsDimension="2">
           <gml:patches>
              <gml:PolygonPatch>
                 <gml:exterior>
                    <gml:Ring>
                       <gml:curveMember>
                          <gml:Curve>
                             <gml:segments>
                                <gml:LineStringSegment>
                                   <gml:posList>118629.351 408359.111 118629.646 408360.435 118637.679 408360.695 118619.346 408364.411 118620.475 408369.426 118615.266 408370.497 118613.919 408370.774</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LineStringSegment>
                                <gml:Arc>
                                   <gml:posList>118613.919 408370.774 118612.801 408365.636 118612.111 408360.776</gml:posList>
                                </gml:Arc>
                                <gml:LineStringSegment>
                                   <gml:posList>118612.111 408360.776 118612.059 408359.772 118612.110 408358.715 118612.410 408357.786 118613.045 408357.067 118613.762 408356.538 118638.182 408351.095 118647.618 408348.889 118651.890 408347.504 118668.913 408341.899</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LineStringSegment>
                                <gml:Arc>
                                   <gml:posList>118668.913 408341.899 118671.576 408340.735 118674.210 408339.346</gml:posList>
                                </gml:Arc>
                                <gml:LineStringSegment>
                                   <gml:posList>118674.210 408339.346 118678.905 408336.675 118687.601 408331.844</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LineStringSegment>
                                <gml:Arc>
                                   <gml:posList>118687.601 408331.844 118690.525 408330.562 118694.026 408329.809</gml:posList>
                                </gml:Arc>
                                <gml:LineStringSegment>
                                   <gml:posList>118694.026 408329.809 118629.351 408359.111</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LineStringSegment>
                             </gml:segments>
                          </gml:Curve>
                       </gml:curveMember>
                    </gml:Ring>
                 </gml:exterior>
              </gml:PolygonPatch>
           </gml:patches>
        </gml:Surface>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use deegree.Geometry.

```
XMLStreamReader r = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(gml));
GMLStreamReader gmlStreamReader = GMLInputFactory.createGMLStreamReader(gmlVersion, r);
geometryObject = gmlStreamReader.readGeometry();
GeometryValidator validator = new GeometryValidator( ( event) -> {
  geometryValidations.add( event);
  return false;
});
if( ! validator.validateGeometry( dgGeometry)) {
  logger.error( "Invalid gml: {}", gml);
  throw new GeometryException("The geometry is not valid");
}
```